# My countdown timer in the embed (Discord.js) switches from 1 minute to 9 minutes. Same with hours or days

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Installed modules: discord.js v12 | easytimer.js

Problem:
Basically what happens to me is that I want to make a countdown timer for my Discord bot and a bug occurs that when the countdown ends instead of putting the end or putting 0 minutes, it comes out 9 hours, 9 days or 9 minutes, it depends on what you put in the beginning. And the code I can't put it in the question because it tells me I have too much code and little text.

[image: screenshot]

Code:

```js
let arg = args[0];

let days = 0,
 hours = 0,
 minutes = 0;

let regx = /(\d*)d|(\d*)h|(\d*)m/g;
let times = arg.match(regx);

times.forEach((x) => {
 let end = x.charAt(x.length - 1);
 if (end == 'd') {
  days = x.slice(0, x.length - 1);
  return;
 }

 if (end == 'h') {
  hours = x.slice(0, x.length - 1);
  return;
 }

 if (end == 'm') {
  minutes = x.slice(0, x.length - 1);
  return;
 }
});

let timer = new timerlib();
timer.start({
 countdown: true,
 startValues: {
  days,
  hours,
  minutes,
 },
 precision: 'minutes',
});

let embedmsg;
message.channel
 .send({ embed: embeds(message.author.tag, days, hours, minutes, args[1]) })
 .then((m) => (embedmsg = m));

timer.on('minutesUpdated', () => {
 minutes = timer.getTimeValues().minutes; //FOR TESTING
 embedmsg.edit({
  embed: embeds(message.author.tag, days, hours, minutes, args[1]),
 });
 console.log(`Minutes updated value of hours is ${hours}`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

there's a bit of a simple solution for this just make it so if day/hour/min/sec = 0 that it disables the decreasing value timer effect on it and locks it 0 until reset and a if it doesn't always reset properly make it check to see if d/h/m/s is higher than 0 if so start countdown process on it